# OpenSSL establish connection between client and server

Tags: c++, encryption, ssl, openssl

Im working on this assignment using Open SSL and C++. I need to establish a secure connection between a client and a server and then transfer a encrypted file. Could anyone give me any references (books, sites, ect) on where to set one up.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should at least get you started:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-openssl.html

Good luck!